# php7 - subtle changes in floats or var_export

Tags: php, php-5.6, php-7.1

Can somebody explain why this works differently in PHP5.6 and 7.1?

```
$ php5.6 -a
php > var_export(1.0);
1

$ php7.1 -a
php > var_export(1.0);
1.0
```

It looks like the float return value is converted in 5.6, but maintained in 7.1.  Or perhaps var_export handles the float differently?

Comment: have a look here - > http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php . Return Type Declarations are now in php7. Also here -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php - first comment

Comment: Ah, so even the internal functions have declared return types.  That makes sense.  But var_export is simply printing string in this case.  Can you explain why the float is exported differently in PHP7?

Comment: Because otherwise var_export would not round-trip. It's a bug fix that was probably excluded from 5.x for BC concerns.